# How to show png in flex with transparent backgroup

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

with the following code,it shows write backgroup now

```
<s:BorderContainer width="100%" height="80%" backgroundAlpha="0">
    <s:Image id="bg"  width="100%" height="100%"/>
    <s:Image id="img" width="100%" height="100%"  />
</s:BorderContainer>
var black:BitmapData  = new BitmapData(bg.width,bg.height,false,0X656565);
bg.source = new Bitmap(black);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(data.bytes); //a png BitmapData
img.source = bitmap;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

`var black:BitmapData  = new BitmapData(bg.width,bg.height,false,0X656565);`
you have already set the transparency to false.
Instead try:

```
var black:BitmapData  = new BitmapData(bg.width,bg.height,true,0X00000000);
```

The third parameter sets the transparency to true and allows the bitmapData to take 32 bit colors which includes the alpha values also. The 32 bit color for the transparency part is passed in the 4th parameter, with the first two digits after the 0x standing for alpha=0.

Hope this helps